# Why won't tailwind connect to my html page?

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I'm working on a Flask app, and couldn't get tailwind to work. So I've moved over to a blank project and followed the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) to see if it would work or not. It did not work. Here are my files from the fresh project.

```
dist/
  output.css
src/
  index.html
  input.css
tailwind.config.js
```

Here is what they look like.

src/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

src/input.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

cd into src and ran open index.html and see no tailwind styling.
I followed the docs to a T. Wondering if I have some environmental issues.

Comment: You probably need to compile the css file. See: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/integrate-tailwindcss-into-flask/

Comment: What does the output file look like?

Comment: @NicolaSpadari it's just got 573 lines of css that was auto generated.

Comment: @Gabe this tutorial doesn't seem to be working for me. i got ```warn - The `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty.
warn - Configure your content sources or your generated CSS will be missing styles.```

Comment: @Gabe i then tried to add the tailwind.config.js file and add the ```["./src/**/*.{html,js}"]``` in the content portion, but I got ```No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.```

Comment: Since you have some tailwind classes in your index.html, this means that tailwind still cannot find the project files. You probably need to adjust the `["./src/**/*.{html,js}"]`, I think realtive to your tailwind.config.js. Which looks fine in your question by the way.

Comment: @Gabe it needs to be pointing toward the html file correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.